# How to render custom shortcode twice in same page with AJAX pagination in wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery

Here is my code. but when i put same shortcode [multi-atts category="apple,lg"] [multi-atts category="nokia"] and click on pagination it works for both as its JS has same class event. Can anyone tell me how can i differentiate this.

I need both shortcode that works in same page without affecting each other post by category wise and with ajax pagination

```
if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ); }
else if ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'page' ); }
else if ( get_query_var( 'pageno' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'pageno' ); }
else if( isset($\_POST\["page"\]) ) { $paged = $\_POST\["page"\]; }
else { $paged = 1; }

if(isset($atts['category']) && !empty($atts['category'])){
        $current_cat = explode(",", $atts['category']);
        //$tax_query = array('taxonomy' => 'brand', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => $atts['category']); 
    } else {
    $current_brand_slug = get_query_var( 'brand' ) ? get_query_var( 'brand' ) : (isset($_POST["brand"]) ? $_POST["brand"] : null);
    
    $current_cat = explode(",", $current_brand_slug);

}
print_r($current_cat);
$args = array(
'post_type'         =\> 'mobiles',
'post_status'       =\> 'publish',
'posts_per_page'    =\> 4,
'paged'             =\> $paged,
'suppress_filter'   =\> false,
'orderby'           =\> 'date',
'order'             =\> 'ASC',
'tax_query' =\> array(
'relation'          =\> 'AND',
array(
'taxonomy' =\> 'brand',
'field' =\> 'slug',
'terms' =\> $current_cat,
)

        ),
    );
    // echo "<pre>";
    // print_r($args);
    // echo "<pre>";
    $cl_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
    if($cl_posts->have_posts() ) { ?>
        <input id="att" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $atts['category']; ?>">
        <section class="section-mobile-listing" data-action="mobile_filter" data-base-url="<?php echo get_post_field( 'post_name'); ?>" > 
        <?php while ( $cl_posts->have_posts() ) {
            $cl_posts->the_post(); ?>
            <h4><?php echo the_title(); ?></h4>
        <?php } wp_reset_postdata();
    } else { ?>
        <div class="col-12">
            <h5 class="no-posts-found">No post found.</h5>
        </div>
    <?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php if ( $cl_posts->have_posts() ) { ?>
        <?php global $wp_append_pageno; $wp_append_pageno = true; ?>
        <div class="section-pagination cst-ajax-listing">
            <?php wp_pagenavi( array( 
                'query' => $cl_posts,
                'format' => '?page=%#%',
            ) ); ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Ajax Filter of page navigation 
        jQuery(document).on("click", ".cst-ajax-listing .wp-pagenavi a", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            const url = new URL(jQuery(this).attr("href"));
            const url_args = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
    
            var nextPage = url_args.get("pageno") ? url_args.get("pageno") : 1;
            update_mobile_listing(nextPage);            
        });
        var ajax_timeout;
        function update_mobile_listing(page) {
            clearTimeout(ajax_timeout);
            section_wrapper = jQuery('.section-mobile-listing');
            current_page = page != "undefined" ? page : 1;
    
        newURL = "/" + section_wrapper.attr("data-base-url");
        
        if (current_page) {
            newURL += "/pageno/" + current_page;
        }
        newURL += "/";
        
        ajax_timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            ajax_search_posts = jQuery.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: app['admin_url'],
                data: {
                    action: section_wrapper.attr("data-action"),
                    pageno: current_page,
                    page: current_page,
                    brand: jQuery('#att').val(),
                },
                beforeSend: function () {
                    
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    section_wrapper.replaceWith(response);
                    
                },
                complete: function (response) {}
            });
        }, 700);
            
        }
    </script>
```

**functions.php File**

```
function multi_atts( $atts ){
return $output; 
ob_start();
$atts = shortcode_atts(
array(
'category' =\> '',
), $atts
);
include(locate_template('template-parts/multi-atts/multi_atts.php', false, false));
return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode( 'multi-atts', 'multi_atts' );

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_mobile_filter', 'mobile_filter');
add_action('wp_ajax_mobile_filter', 'mobile_filter');
function mobile_filter() {
include(locate_template('template-parts/multi-atts/multi_atts.php', false, false));
wp_die();   
}
```

I have tried to keep $atts in hidden input type